# how to mount internal NTFS

Tags: root-access, dual-boot, ntfs

I have a Chuwi hi10 plus.  It is a dual boot windows 10 / android 5.0 tablet that I put on TWRP 3.0.2 rooted it and a custom Lineage OS  Marshmallow 6.0.1 ROM on from Konstakang.com

Chuwi tablets have a funky inability to boot from USB because have a UEFI boot system....  I need to change the Windows password and there is a sticky keys method to copy cmd.exe over sethc.exe and then use the net user command once the command prompt is opened.

I have installed termux and updated the packages and installed tsu for true root access to the filesystem.  But . . . the termux mount does not produce a string of its version from mount -V and while mount -t ntfs /dev/block /mnt/xxx command does not give an error - where I have done a mkdir /mnt/xxx it does claim "no such device". I have used the exact device I know is the windows partition which is ntfs from a "cat /proc/partitions" command

"ntfs-3g" does  not recognize as a command at all, and I even tried the mount_nfsd_fuse setup from https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/guide-mount-internal-windows-partition-t2978679  It must need a touch or something because the file is in /system/xbin but says command not found even invoked as root from that directory

The kernel was compiled from source for the ROM by Konstakang so I do not know if ntfs support is in it ... is there a way to check and / or does anyone have a suggestion how to get that partition mounted rw as ntfs internally ???

The Paragon Ntfs rw mounter that is supposed to work with Total Commander has not appeared to operate as pics show it or once did

Comment: How did you place the mount_nfsd_fuse in the/system/xbin folder? Also does the command have the right permissions?

Comment: Yes it is in /system/xbin and I changed permissions to 755 using Total Comander

Comment: I am wondering if the mount_nfsd_fuse driver is for ARM - and my tablet is x86 Cherry Trail

Comment: Did guide did you follow all the steps in order? 1. Download the mount_nfsd_fuse file from the download link provided below or here
2. Place the the downloaded file in the /system/xbin/ folder using a root enabled file manaager, eg. ES File Explorer, Root Explorer and and change to approriate permission.
3. Open Terminal ( If no terminal app installed, download one from Google Play), and obtain Su permission.
4. Mount the NTFS partitions using the code for example : 
mkdir /storage/D
mount_nfsd_fuse /dev/block/sda2 /storage/D
format : mount_nfsd_fuse /dev/block/(partition) /(mount point)

Comment: Also maybe from a root shell chmod the permissions from the command prompt instead of the file explorer.

Comment: Yes I did all of that - I am an old Unixware Engineer and I got to the bottom of this ... see answer below

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on the mount_nfsd_fuse driver because the ntfs-3g driver uses fuse also and has proprietary kernel hooks in it.  It comes installed from I believe the Ntfs ULB mounter

this is a permission and file issue between two different mount files not in the path when the termux tsu command is the root super user command invoked.  termux is screwing the pooch And the help text of the driver is wrong also

Despite what the help text of the tuxera driver says the format is mount.ntfs /dev/block/xxx /mnt/xxx Not ntfs-3g

so after mounting I get "unsupported reparse point" errors but it does mount the partition as rw

see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1377049 and then https://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/advanced-ntfs-3g.html

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-x86/HyPx8fr_kwc

here is the working one . . . 
|root@chuwi_vi10plus:/ # which mount

/system/bin/mount

does work as mount.ntfs

root@chuwi_vi10plus:/ # exit

whereas this below does not work from the termux mount file

$ tsu

## which mount

/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/mount

## exit

exit
$

which mount
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/mount

does not work

see again for how I figured this out https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-x86/HyPx8fr_kwc/k1LDJ9jwBgAJ

Here is how you know it's working but the usage instructions are wrong   OH JOY

oot@chuwi_vi10plus:/mnt/hold/Windows/System32 # mount.ntfs
ntfs-3g: No device is specified.

ntfs-3g 2015.3.14 external FUSE 29 - Third Generation NTFS Driver
                Configuration type 1, XATTRS are on, POSIX ACLS are off

Copyright (C) 2005-2007 Yura Pakhuchiy
Copyright (C) 2006-2009 Szabolcs Szakacsits
Copyright (C) 2007-2015 Jean-Pierre Andre
Copyright (C) 2009 Erik Larsson

Usage:    ntfs-3g [-o option[,...]]

Options:  ro (read-only mount), windows_names, uid=, gid=,
          umask=, fmask=, dmask=, streams_interface=.
          Please see the details in the manual (type: man ntfs-3g).

Example: ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows

News, support and information:  http://tuxera.com

**Correct Example IS**

Example: mount.ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows

Comment: Good stuff unioncos.

Comment: It should also be mentioned this driver above is 3.14 which is too old fron windows 10 ntfs which uses compression that causes the reparse erros. A plug in is needed against ver 3.23 or better you may need to build yourself from  https://github.com/ebiggers/ntfs-3g-system-compression but at this writing it is read only at the moment